# What is localhost and where is it defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, puma

I just changed from `thin` to `puma` at the recommendation of Heroku.  When I start my rails app using the puma server it responds:

`` => Booting Puma
=> Rails 4.2.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Puma 2.11.3 starting...
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000 ``

However if I go to `http://0.0.0.0:3000` in the browser, which was my old localhost with the thin server, it does not respond. However, if I  open `http://localhost:3000`, then it works. It appears that the definition of localhost has changed.

So, what is `localhost`?  In particular, what sort of object is it, how is it defined, how do I see the actual ip address, and why does puma change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to get Rails to bind to a different ip, the way to do that is with the `-b` option. To bind it to `0.0.0.0` instead of the Rails-default `localhost` you'd want to run something along the lines of `rails s -b 0.0.0.0`

Note: To be explicit, it may not be a bad idea to throw the `-p 3000` option in there too (sets the port), even though that default is not likely to change. More info on the available options can be found by running `rails s -h` as well.

Answer (score 3):

Localhost is the `IPv4` loopback IP address `127.0.0.1`. It is used instead of the hostname of a computer. Localhost can sometimes mean this computer.

For example, directing a web browser installed on a system running an HTTP server to http://localhost will display the home page of the local website.

Here's an interesting Wikipedia article

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: This is useful, but does not tell me how to inspect the value of 'localhost'.