# Python Jupyter Notebook expose local data in the web?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm a total noob at Python, I just downloaded Anaconda and started to use Jupyter Notebook.
I was wondering: since Jupyter Notebook looks web based, should I have any privacy concerns using it? i.e. are the data on my pc exposed out in the web?

Comment: The "web" part is [localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30928493/5858851) - it uses your web browser but doesn't go on the internet.

Comment: Thank you, so I guess, people can't see nor interact with what's on the pc right?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem if you're using the default settings.

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't worry about running notebooks on your localhost. If you want more info (e.g. if you ever intend to run your notebook at a remote server), this [link](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/security.html) will give you some insight regarding security concerns.

TL;DR: no, your data are not exposed.